# Ask Bicep Parameters Conditionally

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

I am creating a an Azure ARM template/Bicep for creating a virtual machine. The template will create both Windows and Linux virtual machines. In the parameters, I want to conditionally ask about the operating system SKU as shown below:

```
@description('Select the OS type to deploy:')
@allowed([
  'Windows'
  'Linux'
])
param operatingSystem string

@description('The Ubuntu version (SKU):')
@allowed([
  'ubuntu2004'
  'ubuntu2004gen2'
])
param ubuntuSKU string

@description('The Desktop Windows version (SKU):')
@allowed([
  'win10'
  'win11'
])
param windowsSKU string
```

Currently, the script asks the user to enter both ubuntuSKU and windowsSKU. I would like to show only the parameter which corresponds to the operatingSystem parameter.

For example, if user enters Windows for operatingSystem, the Bicep only asks parameter windowsSKU from user. If user selects Linux for operatingSystem, the Bicep only shows parameter ubuntuSKU.

One workaround is to combine ubuntuSKU and windowsSKU and refactor the rest of my code. However, I prefer to see if there is a better and smarter solution.

Comment: AFAIk it is not possible, having only one sku parameter sounds good for me.

Answer (score 1):

There's not dependency/branching in params in the bicep file, there are 2 approaches you can consider though:

1. combine the options into a single param and use a dictionary lookup in the template, e.g. https://github.com/bmoore-msft/AzureRM-Samples/blob/master/leap-2020/modules/module.ultimate-vm.json#L165-L176 - this works but the few combinations the better.
2. the other option is to provide the UI for the template and in that ui definition you can set conditions/branching on params.  this is pretty involved but works well provided the template will be deployed via the portal... IDK know of an example that does this exact scenario, but this shows some of the capabilities of the overall UI/experience that may help: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-governance-and-management/using-azure-templatespecs-with-a-custom-ui/ba-p/3586173

Comment: Yes, I end up combining the two parameters. I liked the module.ultimate-vm.json example. There is another thing which I would like to add to my code. Currently, for Ad login (with managed identity), I add the virtual machine login administrator manually. I think you are adding a role via the template.